# How do I change the font size to export the pdf in datatables plug in error

Tags: apache-flex, pdf, datatables, tabletools

The following code gives an error.
Please help me.

My command :

```
D:\flex_sdk_4.6\bin>mxmlc --target-player=11.1.0 -static-link-runtime-shared-lib
raries=true -library-path+=lib ZeroClipboardPdf.as
```

Loading configuration file D:\flex_sdk_4.6\frameworks\flex-config.xml

Error:

> D:\flex_sdk_4.6\bin\ZeroClipboardPdf.as: Error: A file found in a
>   source-path 'ZeroClipboardPdf' must have the same name as the class
>   definition inside the file  'ZeroClipboard'.

Comment: I'm guessing a bit, but it sounds like the ZeroClipboardPdf.as file has a class inside it named ZeroClipboard.  You should change the name of either the file, or the class definition, so that they match.  Your subject line is very confusing; because I'm not sure what this has to do with font sizes, exporting PDFs, or datatables.  Isn't datatables a JQuery plugin?  why would you try to compile that with the Flex SDK?

Comment: There is a plugin to datatables that uses flex to create excel and pdf docs.

Answer (score 1):

The resolved problem.
The file name and class name must be the same...

ZeroClipboardPdf.as in class name changed ZeroClipboard to ZeroClipboardPdf.